# how update InlineQueryResultArticle after click callback_data

Tags: php-telegram-bot

i want update input_message_content in InlineQueryResultArticle after clicking callback_data button

how do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method.

To update message sent via inline query, you should send this request with `inline_message_id` and new `reply_markup` parameters.